# getLastLocation() from LocationClient always returns null

Tags: android, geolocation

I'm using the `LocationClient` to get the user location from the network (no gps).
I instantiate the `LocationClient` during the creation of my fragment

```
 mLocationClient = new LocationClient(getActivity(), this, this);
 mLocationClient.connect();
```

And then later

```
  if (mLocationClient.isConnected())
  {
    currentLocation = mLocationClient.getLastLocation();
  }
```

I am sure that it is connected, but the `getLastLocation()` returns null always.

However, it works using the `LocationManager`.

```
    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    currentLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
```

I know I could just use a listener for location updates, but I would like to understand why `getLastLocation()` always returns null.

Comment: Are you trying in real device or in emulator ?

Comment: @Kedarnath real device, Galaxy S3

Comment: @HemantChandDungriyal I saw it, but it is strange because I call the function after 5 seconds the LocationClient is initialized more or less

Comment: Open the google map init and visit some location, then try you application.

Comment: I did it, but nothing change :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Document says :-

```
public Location getLastLocation ()
```

> Returns the best most recent location currently available.     If a
>   location is not available, which should happen very rarely, null will
>   be returned. The best accuracy available while respecting the location
>   permissions will be returned. This method provides a simplified way to
>   get location. It is particularly well suited for applications that do
>   not require an accurate location and that do not want to maintain
>   extra logic for location updates.

You have to use `onLocationChange()` method to get location:-

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(final Location location) {
      mCurrentLocation = location;
}
```